# CanvasJS line chart generation?

Tags: javascript, php, canvasjs

I am busy trying to make a javascript chart for real-time data display. I found this CanvasJS API. The default code for that [specific chart](http://canvasjs.com/editor/?id=http://canvasjs.com/example/gallery/dynamic/realtime_line/) on their webpage is nice, but of course the part where they get the data, they have left the variable array empty and used a math randomize data function instead, in order that specific data will be randomly generated and used in the graph.

However I would like to full that array with my database data coming from a specific table I would like to use!

***I have tried many things but if I implement my part, the graph won't display anymore. What am I doing wrong?***

Here are the 3 codes I use:

**The default code (just for comparison purpose):**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {

        var dps = []; // dataPoints

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
            title :{
                text: "Live Random Data"
            },          
            data: [{
                type: "line",
                dataPoints: dps 
            }]
        });

        var xVal = 0;
        var yVal = 100; 
        var updateInterval = 20;
        var dataLength = 500; // number of dataPoints visible at any point

        var updateChart = function (count) {
            count = count || 1;
            // count is number of times loop runs to generate random dataPoints.

            for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {   
                yVal = yVal +  Math.round(5 + Math.random() *(-5-5));
                dps.push({
                    x: xVal,
                    y: yVal
                });
                xVal++;
            };
            if (dps.length > dataLength)
            {
                dps.shift();                
            }

            chart.render();     

        };

        // generates first set of dataPoints
        updateChart(dataLength); 

        // update chart after specified time. 
        setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval); 

    }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width:100%;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**My own chart-code, based on the above code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.canvasjs.js" ></script>
    <script src="canvasjs.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.getJSON("data.php", function (result) {

                var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                    data: [
                        {
                            dataPoints: result
                        }
                    ]
                });

                chart.render();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="chartContainer" style="width: 800px; height: 380px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**and my data.php** which displays the following output:

> [{"x":"1","y":"5"},{"x":"2","y":"5"},{"x":"3","y":"4"},{"x":"4","y":"1"},{"x":"5","y":"8"},{"x":"6","y":"9"},{"x":"7","y":"5"},{"x":"8","y":"6"},{"x":"9","y":"4"},{"x":"10","y":"7"}]

```
 <?php
    //header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","WebApplication");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to DataBase: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    } 
    else
    {
    $data_points = array();

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM info");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {        
        $point = array("x" => $row['id'] , "y" => $row['acceleration']);

        array_push($data_points, $point);        
    }

        echo json_encode($data_points, 32); //define('JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK',32);   // Since PHP 5.3.3

    }
    mysqli_close($con);



    ?>
```

Hopefully you have enough info!

Thank you

Mieer

**EDIT**

I swapped the code from 'my own chart' -code for the following, based on @feedback-comment from: *Anjali Jain*

-->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.canvasjs.js" ></script>
    <script src="canvasjs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="canvasjs.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

                $.getJSON("data.php", function (result) {

                var dataPoints = [];

                for (var i = 0; i <= result.length - 1; i++) {
                dataPoints.push({ x: Number(result[i].x), y: Number(result[i].y) });
                }

                var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                data: [
                {
                dataPoints: dataPoints
                }
                ]
                });

                chart.render();
                });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="chartContainer" style="width: 800px; height: 380px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Yet, I still get nothing.

Comment: can you please check my new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61401860/canvas-js-data-sampling-in-php) related to canvasjs?

Answer (score 1):

CanvasJS requires x and y values to be numbers while you are passing strings directly. You can convert them to numbers as shown below

```
$.getJSON("data.php", function (result) {

    var dataPoints = [];

    for (var i = 0; i <= result.length - 1; i++) {
        dataPoints.push({ x: Number(result[i].x), y: Number(result[i].y) });
    }

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        data: [
        {
            dataPoints: dataPoints
        }
        ]
    });

    chart.render();
});
```

Comment: Wayw thank you for your reply, that no one was going to. I will try this out and tell you about it. Thanks:)

Comment: Hi there Anjali Jain, please consider looking at my post above, under EDIT. There I have showed the 'new' code. I still get no graph as an output. I get nothing. Any idea why

Comment: can you please check my new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61401860/canvas-js-data-sampling-in-php) related to canvasjs?