# Removing NaN from date time returned in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, nan, yii2-advanced-app, canvasjs

I am working on `yii2`. In my javascript, I have a formula through which I am getting some data. The data is then passed to chart and chart renders it.

```
var arry_kwh = [];
arry_kwh = <?php echo json_encode($dataPointskWh, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;
var arry_kwh_diff = [];
var i = 0;
for (; i < arry_kwh.length - 1; i++) {
    arry_kwh_diff[i] = {
        label: arry_kwh[i].label + ((arry_kwh[i + 1].label - arry_kwh[i].label) / 2),
        y: (arry_kwh[i + 1].y - arry_kwh[i].y)
    };
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(arry_kwh_diff, null, 2));
```

The returned log is

```
[
{
  "label": "2020-04-01 11:44:13NaN",
   "y": 50
},
{
  "label": "2020-04-01 11:45:49NaN",
  "y": 25
},
{
  "label": "2020-04-01 13:11:24NaN",
   "y": 25
},
{
  "label": "2020-04-02 10:19:08NaN",
   "y": 50
},
{
  "label": "2020-04-02 11:24:38NaN",
  "y": 50
},
{
  "label": "2020-04-04 12:24:38NaN",
  "y": 100
},
{
  "label": "2020-04-05 13:49:38NaN",
  "y": 50
},
{
  "label": "2020-04-05 14:36:38NaN",
  "y": 100
},
{
  "label": "2020-04-05 14:24:38NaN",
  "y": 50
},
{
  "label": "2020-04-08 09:20:41NaN",
  "y": 35
},
{
  "label": "2020-04-08 10:09:38NaN",
  "y": 55
},
{
  "label": "2020-04-08 11:35:33NaN",
  "y": 35
},
{
  "label": "2020-04-08 13:24:38NaN",
  "y": 50
}
 ]
```

The `$dataPointskWh` have

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [label] => 2020-04-01 11:44:13 [y] => 100 ) [1] => Array ( [label] => 2020-04-01 11:45:49 [y] => 150 ) [2] => Array ( [label] => 2020-04-01 13:11:24 [y] => 175 ) [3] => Array ( [label] => 2020-04-02 10:19:08 [y] => 200 ) [4] => Array ( [label] => 2020-04-02 11:24:38 [y] => 250 ) [5] => Array ( [label] => 2020-04-04 12:24:38 [y] => 300 ) [6] => Array ( [label] => 2020-04-05 13:49:38 [y] => 400 ) [7] => Array ( [label] => 2020-04-05 14:36:38 [y] => 450 ) [8] => Array ( [label] => 2020-04-05 14:24:38 [y] => 550 ) [9] => Array ( [label] => 2020-04-08 09:20:41 [y] => 600 ) [10] => Array ( [label] => 2020-04-08 10:09:38 [y] => 635 ) [11] => Array ( [label] => 2020-04-08 11:35:33 [y] => 690 ) [12] => Array ( [label] => 2020-04-08 13:24:38 [y] => 725 ) [13] => Array ( [label] => 2020-04-08 17:12:35 [y] => 775 ) )
```

How can I remove `NaN` from date-time? I have looked into this issue but couldn't find any solution.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: try `console.log(JSON.stringify(arry_kwh_diff, null, 2))` - then paste in the answer from that

Comment: @DenisTsoi Please see my `update 2`

Comment: honestly - this question is beginning to lack focus (i.e. should be split between multiple questions) - as it is asking too much from a single responder to help resolve your problem. SO isn't code review - and the source of why `x` is `null` already tells me that the math function to calculate x is incorrect

Comment: each SO question should only take at max - 20 mins to respond with a high quality answer - however, typically a good enough answer should take 10 mins. (including reading) - either split the question up or it may be flagged as lacking focus

Comment: @DenisTsoi please see my edited question

Comment: what's inside dataPointskWh?

Comment: @Oyeme Kindly see the updated question

Comment: Loop through them and replace it `string.replace("NaN", "")`

Comment: It looks like `((arry_kwh[i + 1].label - arry_kwh[i].label) / 2)` is a problem, since it tries to make arithmetical operations on non-numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it by mapping the `label` attribute and remove the last **3** characters

like this

```
data = data.map(el => el.label.substr(0, el.label.length - 3))
```

> **Notice**: it is recommended the first answer in case of that all objects have **NaN** at the end of line otherwise use the second solution

or by another way, you can `replace` **NaN** with `""`
like this one

```
data = data.map(el => el.label.replace('NaN', ''))
```

Comment: in his sample data, it had `NAN` in each one, but anyway i add two solutions the second one would work in the case, not everyone has `NAN`

Comment: yah you are right at this point, let me edit the answer and add a warning in the first solution